# Chebyshev Polynomials of 1/n

Tags: recurrence-relations, chebyshev-polynomials

The Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind are defined by the recurrence relation:

$$ T_n(x) = 2xT_{n-1}(x) - T_{n-2}(x)$$

By using these polynomials, you can multiply the frequency of a cosine by n via a polynomial, IE:

$$ T_n(\cos x) = \cos nx $$

This can be useful in additive synthesis.

I want to now do the opposite - instead of multiplying the frequency, I want to divide it.  I want to know what $ T_{1/n}(x)$ is.

It's possible to determine $T_{1/2}(x)$ easily with a little bit of algebra:

$$T_2(x) = 2x^2 - 1$$
$$2x^2 = T_2(x) + 1$$
$$x^2 = {T_2(x) + 1 \over 2}$$
$$x = \sqrt{T_2(x) + 1 \over 2}$$

Where $T_1(x) = x$,

$$T_1(x) = \sqrt{T_2(x) + 1 \over 2}$$

or

$$T_{1/2}(x) = \sqrt{x + 1 \over 2}$$

So that's done. However, moving to $T_{1/3}(x)$ is not as easy.

$$ T_3(x) = 4x^3 - 3x $$
$$ 4x^3 = T_3(x) + 3x $$
$$ x^3 = {T_3(x) + 3x \over 4} $$
$$ x = \sqrt[3]{T_3(x) + 3x \over 4} $$

Since $x$ is the thing I'm trying to find, that $3x$ term underneath the cube root isn't helpful.

How can I simplify that last equation?  Furthermore, how can I establish a recurrence relation for $T_{1/n}(x)$?

Comment: It seems like you would not be able to get better than $$ T_3(x) = 4x^3 - 3x $$ and take the solutions of that equation [here is what Wolfram says for arbitrary $4x^3 - 3x = a$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++4x%5E3-3x%3Da+for+x)

Comment: You might assume that you are taking the real root if you can prove there is only one real root and the others are complex conjugates.